# Background Jobs in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to run a query all X seconds on my PostgreSQL database (9.5 on Windows Systems).

I read that you can use Background Jobs to achieve this.

The pgAgent Jobs (https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent-jobs.html) are a good explanation on how to do this.

However on the installation page (https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent-install.html) they mention the security concerns about storing the password on the server / connection string.

Is there another way to run a query all X seconds on the database?
Maybe there is an extension that works like oracle jobs?

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?

Comment: Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 10

Comment: There are several different [authentication methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html) you could try - depends on your specific setup and needs that might be more secure. However, if someone is already on your database server you probably have bigger issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to run a scheduled job. One of them is using pgAgent. 
For windows you can store your password in %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf file. [Here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/libpq-pgpass.html) you can find details. You can also add trust to specific ip and user from server side by changing [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file